# To find Nearest Point

Tags: matlab

We have set of (x,y) coordinates in matrix form. we want to fit a curve through those points. but it does not take points in sequence(nearest point) rather it takes the points arranged according to the sequence arranged in matrix

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to fit a curve in traditional approximation sense (i.e. a functional approximation f(x) that approximates the ordinates) or do you want a parametric curve fitted??

Comment: yes we want to fit parametric curve

Comment: So why not simply sort the points into the order that you actually want them. In your case it sounds like you want the points ordered based on their proximity. You will still need to define a start point and then iteratively evaluate the nearest point. I think you should edit your question to clarify exactly what you want, even including an image of your data, and your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think @mathematician1975 is quite right, you do not need the points arranged in sequence before do curve fitting, at least for OLS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares If you do want the sequence, sort the coordinates by variable is fine. In both case, you do not need the nearest point.

Comment: sort command does not help because suppose we have points A(1,1) B(2,5) C(3,2) D(5,4) in the same sequence in matrix. Now we want to fit curve through points A C D B but when we try to fit curve through above points it passes through sequence A B C D(i.e, Sequence given in matrix) that's why we need nearest point (since C is nearer to A than B)

Comment: @user2754278 I also have difficulty in understanding what are you trying to do. Please provide more data and describe the problem clearer. Otherwise, we cannot help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear but based on your comments, you could simply create a new matrix of ordered points by deciding on a start point and using the Euclidean norm to identify the nearest neighbour and add that to your new matrix. Continue this for each point (of course making sure that you exclude all previous points from the nearest neighbour evaluation at each step) until you have just one point left.

Once this is done you have your points in the order you want and can fit your parametric curve accordingly.

It is quite possible that there is a magic command in matlab that will do this for you but if there is I am not aware of it. If there is I am sure you will get an answer telling you so in due course.

If not you can still obtain what (I think) you want with loops and the `norm` function. It may not be optimal but it will give you what you want.